# Getting a point of circle from a number?

Tags: java

I have a circle of let's say 10 of radius with the center `x=0` `y=0`. And I have a number n (e.g. 3). I want to get a point from that circle. Here is an explanation with an image:

[image: circle]

So if `n=0`, the method would return `0;-6`
And if `n=1`, the method would return `3;-5`
etc.
But the method would receive parameters like the unit between each n etc.

Comment: Is it a circle or a sphere? Circles don't have z-values

Comment: It's a circle, I meant y not z

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion depends on how you name the axes; circles on an X-Z plane do have a position along the Z coordinate

Comment: @alex how would I use that?

Comment: I don't understand your "specification". If it's "pick from the list of all integer points on a cirle of some unspecified radius (but 6 only yields the four points along the cardinal direction), then your image doesn't match due to symmetry. Two points per quadrant above the x-axis, but three below?

Comment: @JanDvorak The image isn't really accurate, I didn't do it right, normally everything should be symmetrical with the same distance between each point (that I define as an argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a circle is

```
x = x0 + r * cos(a)
y = y0 + r * sin(a)
```

with (x0, y0) the center of the circle and a in 0...2Pi

so if you want y given x you will have :

```
sin(a) = (y - y0)/r
```

so

```
a = arcsin((y - y0)/r) if ((y - y0)/r is in -PI/2..PI/2)
a = -arcsin((y - y0)/r) if ((y - y0)/r is in -PI..-PI/2 or PI/2..PI)
a is undefine elsewhere
```

therefore

```
y = y0 + r * sin(arcsin((y - y0)/r)) if ((y - y0)/r is in -PI/2..PI/2))
y = y0 + r * sin(-arcsin((y - y0)/r)) if ((y - y0)/r is in -PI..-PI/2 or PI/2..PI))
y is undefine elsewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [roots of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), it will give you the exponential form of a complex on the circle. You can then use the [Euler formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to get the real coordinates of your point. Of course, since your circle is not unitary, you must take into account its radius.